# ExoPlayer getCurrentTrackGroups() deprecated

Tags: java, android, exoplayer

Can someone please assist with this Android Java ExoPlayer code to detect audio format. I modified this method from an Exo developer GitHub comment from 2020 and it works, but in Android Studio it's telling me the function is already depreciated and I can't figure out how to update it?

This method works, but AS gives waring "'getCurrentTrackGroups()' is deprecated"

```
private static Format detectAudioFormat() {
    TrackGroupArray trackGroups = player.getCurrentTrackGroups();
    for (int i = 0; i < trackGroups.length; i++) {
        TrackGroup trackGroup = trackGroups.get(i);
        for (int j = 0; j < trackGroup.length; j++) {
            Format format = trackGroup.getFormat(j);
            if (MimeTypes.isAudio(format.sampleMimeType)) {
                return format;
            }
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

After changing getCurrentTrackGroups() to getCurrentTracks() AS now gives errors "Cannot resolve symbol 'length'" and "Cannot resolve method 'get' in 'Tracks'"

```
private static Format detectAudioFormat() {
    Tracks trackGroups = player.getCurrentTracks();
    for (int i = 0; i < trackGroups.length; i++) {
        TrackGroup trackGroup = trackGroups.get(i);
        for (int j = 0; j < trackGroup.length; j++) {
            Format format = trackGroup.getFormat(j);
            if (MimeTypes.isAudio(format.sampleMimeType)) {
                return format;
            }
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The new method is a little different - it is explained in the online documentation but it may to be clear how the new and old methods relate: https://exoplayer.dev/track-selection.html

The new method getCurrentTracks() returns a list of Track.Group, and each entry in this list is a group that contains individual tracks with the same content in different formats.

You can then iterate through each track in a group to get information about that individual track - e.g. to see if the track is supported as in the example at the above link:

```js
for (Tracks.Group trackGroup : tracks.getGroups()) {
  // Group level information.
  @C.TrackType int trackType = trackGroup.getTrackType();
  boolean trackInGroupIsSelected = trackGroup.isSelected();
  boolean trackInGroupIsSupported = trackGroup.isSupported();
  for (int i = 0; i < trackGroup.length; i++) {
    // Individual track information.
    boolean isSupported = trackGroup.isTrackSupported(i);
    boolean isSelected = trackGroup.isTrackSelected(i);
    Format trackFormat = trackGroup.getTrackFormat(i);
  }
}
```